# Set Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I need to format a flat array into a multidimensional array following client's template. 
Here is my flat array :

```
$client = array(
    'LastName'        => 'DUPOND',
    'FirstName'       => 'JEAN',
    'Email'           => 'jdupond@free.fr',
    'Address1'        => '126 QUAI BACALAN',
    'ZipCode'         => '33160',
    'City'            => 'BORDEAUX',
    'Country'         => 'FR'
);
```

And here is my client's template :

```
    $Template = array(
    'Header'       => array(
        'Context'      => array(
                'LastName'     => '',
                'FirstName'    => ''
        ),
        'Localization' => array(
            'ZipCode'      => '',
            'City'         => '',
            'Country'      => '',
        ),
        'Address1'     => '',
    ),
    'Options'      => array(
        'Email'        => '',
    ),
);
```

So in the end i need to have a array that looks like :

```
$Template = array(
'Header'       => array(
    'Context'      => array(
            'LastName'     => 'DUPOND',
            'FirstName'    => 'JEAN'
    ),
    'Localization' => array(
        'ZipCode'      => '33160',
        'City'         => 'BORDEAUX',
        'Country'      => 'FR',
    ),
    'Address1'     => '126 QUAI BACALAN',
),
'Options'      => array(
    'Email'        => 'jdupond@free.fr',
));
```

But it must work with any kind of template.
It should work even if tomorrow clients decide to change template structure.

So from a day to another, the template can suddently become :

```
$Template = array(
'Header' => array(
    'LastName' => '',
    'FirstName' => '',
    'Localization' => array(
        'ZipCode' => '',
        'Deeper' => array(
            'EvenDeeper' => array(
                'Deepest' => array(
                    'City' => '',
                    'Country' => ''
                )
            )
        )
    )
),
'Options' => array(
    'Email' => '',
    'Address1' => ''
));
```

and the function will still work !

Comment: What's the problem? Just replace all the values in the new array assignment with references to the original array?

Comment: I don't see how you can have something that will work if the target multidimensional array is going to change

Comment: Tip: look into recursive functions if the structure may change and it needs to work for arrays of any depth

Comment: I tried to do a recursive methode.
I manage to set every key with the correct value, but i get stuck in coming back to the final array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function fillTemplate(&$template, $client) {
    foreach ($template as $key => &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            fillTemplate($value, $client);
        } elseif (isset($client[$key])) {
            $value = $client[$key];
        }
    }
}

$result = $Template; // Make copy of template
fillTemplate($result, $client);
```

This walks the template recursively. When it reaches a leaf node, it replaces the value with the corresponding value from `$client`. It uses reference variables as the argument and in `foreach` so that the changes are made directly to the template. To preserve the original template, I make a copy of it before calling `fillTemplate`.

Comment: It should work even if tomorrow clients decide to change template structure. So i can only focus on template keys. And i can not change the template.

Comment: Like I said, it's not possible if the template can change. Where do the template keys come from if you don't have them in your code?

Comment: Well abviously everything can change except for template keys name.But sometimes it will be in first dimention of the array and an other time in third dimention

Comment: What else is there other than the template key names?

Comment: Can you post an example variation of the template that shows what you're talking about?

Comment: `$Template = array(
'Header'       => array(
    'LastName'     => '',
    'FirstName'    => '',
    'Localization' => array(
        'ZipCode'      => '',
        'Deeper' => array(
            'EvenDeeper' => array(
                'Deepest' => array(
                    'City'         => '',
                    'Country'      => '',
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'Options'      => array(
    'Email'        => '',
    'Address1'     => '',
),`

Comment: You should put that in the question.

Comment: @Barmar I have deleted my answer. +1!